# Making a button programmatically play a sound in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uikit

I want to create a button and make it play a sound when it is touched. So far, I can make the button, but I'm having trouble making it play the sound. Here's what I have:

```
//loads wav file into SoundID
NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"medic_taunts01" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);

//creates button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[scrollview addSubview:button]

//this line is the problem
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(AudioServicesPlaySystemSound((SoundID)) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

For some reason, xcode won't let me play a sound directly from the button click. How can I make touching the button play the SoundID?

Comment: if you have resolved this then accept correct answer to help others who having same issue.

Comment: @BhushanUparkar ditto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button action method must have the following signature:

```
-(void)buttonActionMethod:(id)inSender
```

That means you cannot call a system method directly. For what you are trying to do, I would suggest this method:

```
//loads wav file into SoundID
NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"medic_taunts01" ofType:@"wav"]];
SystemSoundID soundID
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &soundID );
self.SoundID = soundID;

//creates button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[scrollview addSubview:button]

//this line is the problem
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(playButtonSound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Note the conversion of `SoundID` to a property (I trust you know how to make those). Then define this method:

```
-(void)playButtonSound:(id)inSender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.SoundID);
}
```

Of course, if you have more than one button, each with different sounds, you will need to get a little more creative here with mapping sound IDs to the button.

Comment: oops! you posted your answer while I was creating one :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your edited answer. Hope this helps:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

      NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"medic_taunts01" ofType:@"wav"]];
      AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);

      //creates button
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
      [scrollview addSubview:button]

      //this line was causing problem
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


}


-(void)playSound:(id)sender{

       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound((SoundID)

  }
```